# Unity VR Oculus Rift

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I have implemented basic player interactions, look, move, grab and move items and it all works fine.

The OVRGrabbable script (part of OVR plugin) makes the grabbed object`s rigidbody kinematic.

As a result, the object in hand is passing through other colliders. When the item is released everything works great but while in hand it passes through all colliders. It does not stop when it hits other colliders resulting passing with the object through a wall and etc.

I know that the OVRGrabbable script makes the object kinematic and that is why this happens. Can I do something to change this default behavior ? I need the object to stop when it hits the table, wall, not to pass through it.

Did anyone tried to solve this? Any advice ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have abandoned using the official Oculus SDK. Instead I have implemented VRTK SDK which is working great, and it supports a wider range of VR devices.

If anybody has a similar problem, VRTK solves this problem with colliders and other minor fixes.

https://github.com/thestonefox/VRTK